# How to calculate pos tagger accuracy by each tag

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, nltk, pos-tagger

I've made a keras model pos tagger using the NLP4Hackers' [article](https://www.google.com.br/amp/s/nlpforhackers.io/lstm-pos-tagger-keras/amp/) as baseline. Currently I can computate the accuracy directly over the keras *model.evaluate* method. Acctualy, I would like to calculate the accuracy by tag as show below:

'JJ': 98.56 accuracy,

'NNS': 99.01 accuracy

'NN': 96.43 accuracy

...

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

All the evaluation metrics that you can imagine are in Scikit-learn

You have two possibilities, either you compute the [confusion matrix](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix) 
and you look the diagonal values.

```
y_true = ["cat", "ant", "cat", "cat", "ant", "bird"]
y_pred = ["ant", "ant", "cat", "cat", "ant", "cat"]
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=["ant", "bird", "cat"])
array([[2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2]])
```

Or you compute the [F1 score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html#sklearn.metrics.f1_score) label by label

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average=None)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm currently using [sklearn.metrics.classification_report](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) because it display **precision**, **recall** and  **f1-score** in a very simple way.